# Is type conversion faster for Objects or Primitives in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Given these two examples:

```
var myNumber = 10; //primitive
```

and

```
var myNumber = new Number(10); //object
```

**Which performs faster when a type conversion occurs?**

```
var myString = myNumber.toString(); //convert to string
```

I assume that object type conversion is faster since the primitive gets converted to an object to respond to the expression and then back to primitive again.

Comment: This would of course depend on the implementation and its specific optimizations. Testing is the only way to tell, but I'd suggest using primitives in general.

Comment: I'd also test the primitive with string concatenation as the means of conversion. `var myString = myNumber + "";`

Comment: This question and many more can be answered by using http://jsperf.com/.

Comment: According to the [ES5 spec](http://es5.github.com/#x9.8), `ToPrimitive` is called on all objects before they are converted to strings, so that makes me believe that the *primitives* are faster, since there is no conversion step before `ToString`.

Comment: There are "less steps" for primitive values in ECMAScript; if this translates to a noticeable real-world performance/differences requires a benchmark.

Comment: It seems counter-intuitive, but converting from primitives is apparently faster. At least on my tests: http://jsperf.com/object-versus-primitive-number-conversion-to-string

Comment: Today has turned out to be Premature Optimization Day around here :-)

Comment: @bfavaretto: I don't see why this is counterintuitive. Using only primitives will not create all the object overhead, as I'm quite sure modern engines do not create the object wrapper described in the spec for property lookup (http://es5.github.com/#x8.7.1).

Comment: @Bergi The wrapper creation was exactly what made me think that. You must be right, browsers probably optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will summarize the excellent comments to an answer. Thanks to theSystem, RocketHazmat, pst, bfavaretto and Pointy!

> Which performs faster? I assume…

You can only test, test, test. [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) is a good choice to do that. [Tests show](http://jsperf.com/object-versus-primitive-number-conversion-to-string) that primitive values concatenated with empty string are by far the fastest method - function calls are costly. This holds especially true if the variables are not cached but instantiated each time ([test by Geuis](http://jsperf.com/num-type-conversion)).

> object type conversion is faster since the primitive gets converted to an object to respond to the expression and then back to primitive again

This is only what the EcmaScript specification describes for behaviour ([section 8.7.1](http://es5.github.com/#x8.7.1), [section 9.8](http://es5.github.com/#x9.8)), not what current engines do. They will not create any object overhead, but use the internal primitive values only. Do not trust the number of steps in the spec!

However, not [calling](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.3) the `Number.prototype.toString` function ([section 15.7.4.2](http://es5.github.com/#x15.7.4.2)) - even if it is native - but getting directly to `ToString` via the `addition` operator ([section 11.6.1 step 7](http://es5.github.com/#x11.6.1)) will be faster.

In general, do not try to [prematurely optimize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization) but only when you really get performance problems (you hardly will from this code). So use primitive values for simplicity, and either `.toString()` or `+""` depending on what you find easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive number with type casting is the fastest of all.

http://jsperf.com/num-type-conversion